# Triggering local-exec provisioner on resource change

Tags: terraform

We're needing to run a 3rd party python script to do some testing/validation on RDS resources provisioned by terraform.

We use Terraform Enterprise where the runtime environment is simplistic and installing software, etc in the "worker" environment is expensive (I'm aware this is against recommendations). The script takes some order of minutes to run on top of the bootstrap of prerequisites (python libraries, test case data, etc).

I'd like to ensure the script is run when terraform detects *any* change (and only when changes occur) to the RDS resources under its control.

```
resource "null_resource" "validate_rds_resource" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command =  format("%s %s", 
      "./scripts/validate-rds.sh", 
      join(" ", aws_db_instance.rds_instance.id)
    )
    on_failure  = fail
    working_dir = path.module
  }

  triggers = {
    # What goes here to instruct terraform to react on any change to
    # aws_db_instance.rds_instance
  }
}
```

The [docs of `null-resource`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource) discuss how to trigger on a particular attribute of the resource changing (e.g. `.id` here)

```
  # Changes to any instance of the cluster requires re-provisioning
  triggers = {
    cluster_instance_ids = join(",", aws_instance.cluster.*.id)  # Tracking .id
  }
```

However, I'm after the case of needing to react when *any* attribute of the resources changes (Tags, option/parameter groups, engine particulars, etc,). Maybe a hash of the resource? But how?